# Web API 2 requires trailing slash for custom attribute routing to work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api2

I have created a Web API 2 project and although the APIs work fine, I must enter a trailing slash for them to do so.

**This results in a 404**

```
http://www.myURL.com/api/v1/get/addressfromlatlong/UK/50.9742794/-0.1146699
```

**This shows the JSON response as intended**

```
http://www.myURL.com/api/v1/get/addressfromlatlong/UK/50.9742794/-0.1146699/
```

I have another controller with a custom action that works fine. The only difference is that this has one parameter that is an integer...

It seems to be something to do with the decimal type as if I make a slight variation in the URL and use a parameter, the API returns the results without issue:

**This variation also shows the JSON response as intended**

```
http://www.myURL.com/api/v1/get/addressfromlatlong/UK/50.9742794/?longitude=-0.1146699
```

It's not the end of the world but I also use Swagger to generate my API documentation and that automatically uses the first of the above URLs and includes built-in testing which, of course, fails. That's not so good for any developers who are referencing the API docs.

Can anyone explain why this may be happening and how I get it to work without the trailing slash?

**Route Config**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

**Custom attributes and Controller Action**

```
[Route("get/addressfromlatlong/UK/{latitude:decimal=0}/{longitude:decimal=0}")]
    public AddressDetails GetAddressDetailsByLatLong(decimal latitude, decimal longitude)
    {
        AddressDetails addressDetails = repository.GetAddressDetailsByLatLong(latitude, longitude);
        return addressDetails;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `NOT WORK`? Can you show us the code and Route config?

Comment: Maybe you have the tailing "/" at the end of your Route attribute?

Comment: Yes, I apologise for my lack of previous info (was in a rush). I have updated the question now to post the code and Route config as requested.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/modules). Without it IIS thinks it is a file request with extension as number part after decimal point. File is not found, 404.

Comment: Wow. That makes absolute sense now you point it out. Quick question. I found this post http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/dont-use-modules-runallmanagedmodulesfo.html suggesting the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests approach is a waste of resources. I have implemented the approach outlined in the blog. Does this seem an improved approach - considering I just need the URL routing module to run on all requests?

Comment: Yes it is better approach. Hovewer it can cause errors, so you should test and see if it works well for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code in your web.cong file:

```
<system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
 </modules>
</system.webServer>
```