# Urls that don't finish with / won't load properly other embebed pages

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, model-view-controller

Has anyone encountered this problem?

I have been working with c# MVC in Visual Studio and when we publish our pages if the user tries to access the page and doesn't end the URL with / some pages won't load properly.

We use a lot that we have a main page and then somewhere in the middle is a div that is updated through javascript (I know that's what the render from mvc does when using the layout, but our boss doesn't like it that way and also it tends to interfere with her multiple layers of javascript)

It is these div parts that are loaded this way that won't load when the main page doesn't have a / at the end.

we have tried using @url.action and also hard typing the URL of the second page in the javascript and both yield the same result.

Is there a way to configure the project so that it doesn't matter whether the url that was typed in the browser has the / at the end?

EDIT: Added javascript function

```
function refreshdiv(divid, url) {
            var seconds = 15;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                context: document.body,
                async: true,
                timeout: 15000,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#" + divid).html(data);
                    $("#" + divid).find("script").each(function (i) {
                        eval($(this).text());
                    });

                }
            });
```

Thanks in Advance for any help

Comment: can i see how do you call in javascript

Comment: I Updated the question

Comment: I ran into something similar a couple of years ago.  Have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739351/web-api-2-requires-trailing-slash-for-custom-attribute-routing-to-work

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the help but I still need help with this issue...